# React function being called multiple times(every second)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, material-ui

I am using React and rendering a modal from Material UI. The way the modal is rendered is it has to be a part of the body of code. So I added it to the bottom of the page. The state determines whether or not the modal is open. The issue is that I can see that a function that is in the modal is being called multiple times. And very rapidly. Like more than once each second. Please see my code:

```
class ComponentName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countries: [],
      isButtonDisabled: false,
      formError: false,
      showModalCta: false,
      showModal: false,
      iframeUrl: ''
    };
  }

   handleClose = () => {
     this.setState({
       showModal: false
     });
   };


   handleShowModal = () => {
     this.setState({
       showModal: true
     })
   }


  showModalContent = () => {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { iframeUrl } = this.state;


    getiframeUrl().then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        iframeUrl: res.level2VerificationUrl
      });
    });

    return (
      <Paper className={classes.modalPaper}>
        <iframe src={iframeUrl} width="500px" height="500px" />
      </Paper>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const {
      classes, history, firstName, lastName, country, region, address, city, dob, phone, smsCode, postalCode, actions
    } = this.props;
    const {
      countries, formError, isButtonDisabled, showCta, showModal
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

          <Modal className={classes.modal} open={showModal} onClose={this.handleClose}>
            {this.showModalContent()}
          </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Its pretty much calling that function to get the url every second. But I dont quite understand why this is the behavior. Been doing research on this but no answers. Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: Which function is firing repeatedly? What is `this.showModalContent()`?

Comment: You have a `this.setState` call in a render function (`this.showModalContent`). This means everytime the component renders it will call `this.setState` which in turn will make the component rerender causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @JacobSmit I apologize for the confusion. I accidentally mispelled the function name. I just corrected it. So it is calling the "getiframeUrl" function that is in the 'showModalContent' arrow function multiple times it seems. But then again, that could be side effect of calling the showModalContent function in a unusual way

Comment: Without further information about how your component should function my initial suggestion would be to load the iframe URL via `getiframeUrl()` in the `componentDidMount()` and remove the call from `this.showModalContent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showModalContent will be executed on every "state change" of the component (on every render).
There (from what I see) you are making a call to a promise (getiframeUrl) and you are setting the state of the component (which makes it change state).

Hence: Render -> showModalContent -> change state -> re-render -> showModalContent -> ... (infinite loop).

My advice is that you do the setState of iframeUrl only in the componentDidMount. Something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   const { iframeUrl } = this.state;

   getiframeUrl().then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        iframeUrl: res.level2VerificationUrl
      });
   });
}

showModalContent = () => {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <Paper className={classes.modalPaper}>
        <iframe src={iframeUrl} width="500px" height="500px" />
      </Paper>
    );
  };
```